# Recast maximization as minimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I hope you can help me.

I would like to know which are the conditions to transform a maximization problem into a minimization one.

I have the following problem

$
Q: \max_{x,y} ~ f(y) / g(x) ~~ s.t. ~ (x,y) \in \Omega,
$

where $ f(y) > 0 $ is linear,  $ f(x) > 0 $ is convex, $ \Omega $ is a convex set.

I am tempted to recast $ Q $ as a minimization problem as shown below

$
P: \min_{x,y} ~ g(x)/f(y) ~~ s.t. ~ (x,y) \in \Omega,
$

where the problem is convex since $ g(x)/f(y) $ is a quadratic-over-linear function.

I have made some simulations for a few different functions and I note that they are equivalenet. But I cannot say for sure if this equivalence will always hold. By pure math manipulation I have not been able to go from $Q$ to $P$. Do you know the conditions for this to always be true?

Comment: Why don't you just change the sign of the objective function?

Comment: Yes, it is the same thing. Making $z$ large can equivalently be done by making $1/z$ small.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to see this in a more formal way rather than by intuition.